# Need filtering help in PowerShell script

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.1

I have an array with some server data and have following script:

```
Write-Host "`nRemoving servers' accounts from AD:" -ForegroundColor Green

for ($j=0; $j-le $screenObj.Length; $j++)
{if (($screenObj[$j].Domain -ne "Unknown") -and ($screenObj.Where({$_ -ne ""})))
 {Try {Remove-ADComputer $screenObj[$j].ServerName -Server $screenObj[$j].Domain -Confirm:$false -WhatIf
  Write-Host $screenObj[$j].ServerName "deleted." -ForegroundColor DarkYellow}
  Catch {Write-Host $screenObj[$j].ServerName ":" $_.Exception.InnerException.Message -ForegroundColor Red}
 }
 }
```

It gives me following output:

```
Removing servers' accounts from AD:
What if: Performing the operation "Remove" on target "CN=Server1,OU=Application - With WINS,OU=Application,OU=W2K3,OU=Servers,OU=MY,DC=corp,DC=mycorp,DC=net".
Server1 deleted.
What if: Performing the operation "Remove" on target "CN=Server2,OU=Application - With WINS,OU=Application,OU=W2K3,OU=Servers,OU=MY,DC=corp,DC=mycorp,DC=net".
Server2 deleted.
What if: Performing the operation "Remove" on target "CN=Server3,OU=IIS,OU=W2K8,OU=Servers,OU=Europe,DC=TKMAXX,DC=mycorp,DC=net".
Server3 deleted.
What if: Performing the operation "Remove" on target "CN=Server4,OU=IIS,OU=W2K8,OU=Servers,OU=Europe,DC=TKMAXX,DC=mycorp,DC=net".
Server4 deleted.
 : The argument is null or empty. Provide an argument that is not null or empty, and then try the command again.
```

I couldn't identify why is the last line in the output is coming as
`: The argument is null or empty. Provide an argument that is not null or empty, and then try the command again.`

Can someone explain this and help me to resolve this unknown warning?
Also, please let me know if there are better ways to achieve the desired output.
**Note:** I'm using `-WhatIf` option so that the servers aren't actually deleted.

Comment: Change `$j-le $screenObj.Length` to `$j -lt $screenObj.Length` in the `for` loop. (`less-than`, instead of `less-than-or-equals`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `for` loop condition counts from 0 through `$screenObj.Length`, meaning that in the last iteration of the loop `$screenObj[$i]` will always resolve to `$null` - change the `-le` operator to `-lt` to fix it:

```
for ($j = 0; $j -lt $screenObj.Length; $j++)
{ 
  # ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you @mathias-r-jessen for rescuing me.
I was confident that I was so close but I failed to notice that incorrect operator.

The issue is resolved :-)